# How to publish a post within certain period

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and I want to post a post within 3 days of submitting it.

So for example and the post is not available initially but after three days the post appears automatically and can be viewed.

Comment: you can use cron

Comment: please refer this article, https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-task-scheduling-with-cron-job-example

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `published_at` field on your `POST` model and condition your application to only show `posts` which are past the date and time.

For the `Post` removal part, you could create a scheduled task to remove the `published_at` value from the post 3 days after that date and time.